# SharePoint product configuration wizard was stuck since one day in one of app server where i installed reporting services as in share point mode

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

SharePoint product configuration wizard was stuck since one day in one of app server where i installed reporting services as in share point mode.

i recently updated sharepoint farm with september 2016 CU

In event viewer i saw below error every time

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Service.DoWorkTimerJob
>   (ID 756b2c2a-ad92-4406-a1e6-94f59f242d4a) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.

Comment: how many servers in the farm? is it successful any of the server?

Comment: hi 3 servers , configuration wizard not finish in reporting server

Comment: i need to install any updates related reporting services it already sql server reporting services sp1

Comment: The value for UrlRoot in rsreportserver.config is not valid. The default value will be used instead. (Application: ReportingService- i got this errors also

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the 2016 version of rsSharePoint.msi.

Comment: i downloaded sql server 2012 sp2 reporting services add-in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43344  and installed the same issue again